Visual Studio 2022 не создает новый проект. Ошибка
По какой то причине не создаются проекты vue с asp.net, react с asp.net.
Ругается на недопустимые знаки в пути, хотя таких в пути нет.
Пробовал переустанавливать VS, не помогло.
Возможно кто-то сталкивался?

Пути:

UPDATE 1:
На втором ПК с аналогичными path всё спокойно создаётся. Если нет npm, ругается, ставишь, проблем нет.
На "проблемном" пк, даже при отсутствующем npm и Node.js, выдаёт ошибку "Путь содержит недопустимые знаки." Копаю дальше...
UPDATE 2:
Шаблон под React создаётся через командную строку (dotnet new react) без пробем, а шаблона для Vue в list нет?


Покажи строками пути которые у тебя используются

C:\Users\rea\source\repos\VueApp1м   C:\Program Files\dotnet\
